# Double Integral with Gauss- Hermite for one component

Tags: python, integration

I am trying to perform the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{r'\left(e^{-r'^2/2\sigma^2}\right)\left(r-r'\cos(\theta-\theta')\right)}{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\theta-\theta')}dr'dθ'$$

Using Gauss-Hermite for $r$ and Simpson 1/3 rule for $\theta$ with no success. I can't find my mistake but the output should look like Fig. 2. This was my code (sorry for my bad formatting, this is my first time uploading here).

$\sigma$ should be assumed as 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special as ss

def rt(d, r, theta ,sig):
    return r*(d-r*np.cos(theta))*np.exp(-r**2/(2*sig**2))/(d**2+r**2-2*d*r*np.cos(theta))
def intheta1(d, r, b, sig, N):
    h = b/N
    I = rt(d,r,0,sig) + rt(d,r,b,sig)
    for i in range(1, N, 2):
        I += 4*rt(d, r, i*h, sig)
    for j in range(2, N, 2):
        I += 2*rt(d, r, j*h, sig)
    return I*h/3

def intr1(d, b, sig, N, M):
    x, w = ss.roots_hermitenorm(N)
    s = 0
    for k in range(N):
        s += intheta1(d, x[k], b, sig, M)*w[k]
    return s/2

ps = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
qs = intr1(xs, 2*np.pi, 1, 1000, 90)

plt.plot(ps, qs)
```

[image: My Result]

[image: The actual result]

Comment: I cannot match `rt` function in your Python script with your formula written above. Are you sure the formula is correctly implemented? Also, please remove the image and write your formula by using our LaTeX here.

Comment: Did my best, hopefully it is a little more understandable.

Comment: Still I can't match it with your Python implementation. For example: in your formula you have: $\exp{(-\frac{(r^{'})^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}})}$ but in your code you have: `np.exp(-r**2/(2*sig**2))` and as far as I understand you use `d` in your code for showing $r^{'}$, but it's clearly in conflict with your formula. So, something is wrong here for sure...

Comment: I am using r as r' and d as r....My goal is to make the graph of the magnetic field (the result of the Integral) as a function of r (represented by d in python)

Comment: Gauss-Hermite quadrature is for an integral with $-\infty$ to $\infty$ limits, see it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature, but clearly your limit for $r$ is finite and positive. How would you map it? That's the problem with your implementation.

Comment: I guess being and even function I could make the Integral with limits $-\infty$ to $\infty$ limits and divide it by two. At least that was my initial thought, that's why I am returning s/2

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you can easily map a region of $[0,5]$ to $[-\infty,\infty]$ easily without a complex changing variable. More convenient way to do this is to use Gauss quadrature and map $[0,5]$ region to $[-1,1]$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature

Comment: Yes but $[0,5]$ is the region of interest for my graph (for r). R' stills goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. R is for example my position and r' is the contribution of the infinite wire to the magnetic field.

Comment: Is $r^{'}$ radial distance in polar coordinate? If yes, $r^{'}$ is always a positive number and at most it varies between 0 to $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: Still, I believe that despite my region of interest for r being $[0,5]$, I have to integrate r' from 0 to $\infty$ as that's the contribution from the wire

Comment: Would you mind adding integration limits?

Comment: Done.
I have been studying this type of numerical integration and I believe I understood my mistake. First of all I am using gauss-Hermite which work with limits {-\infty}  to {\infty} so using the fact that this function is even makes it so that to integrate from 0 to {\infty} I have to use np.abs() of my integration variable. Also, using Gauss-Hermite makes it so that I have to remove the exponential function. In this case I am using  roots_hermitenorm() so I had to find a way to remove exp(-r^2/2) from the expression.

Comment: @TomásLopes, I think that your previous comment should be added to your answer.

Comment: @nicoguaro Sure, good idea

Answer (score 1):

I have been studying this type of numerical integration and I believe I understood my mistake. First of all I am using Gauss-Hermite which work with limits ${-\infty}$  to ${\infty}$ so using the fact that this function is even makes it so that to integrate from $0$ to ${\infty}$ I have to use `np.abs()` of my integration variable. Also, using Gauss-Hermite makes it so that I have to remove the exponential function. In this case I am using  `roots_hermitenorm()` so I had to find a way to remove $\exp(-r^2/2)$ from the expression.
I got to these answer which is currently working flawlessly.

```
python
def integral_theta(r, rline, theta, sigma):
    rline = np.abs(rline)
    return np.exp((-(rline)**2*(1-sigma**2))/2/sigma**2) * rline * (r - rline*np.cos(theta))/(r**2 + rline**2 - 2*r*rline*np.cos(theta))

def i_theta(r, rline, sigma):
    a, b = 0, 2*np.pi
    N = 100
    h = (b-a)/N
    s_odd = 0
    for k in range(1,N,2):
        s_odd += integral_theta(r, rline, a+k*h, sigma)
    s_even = 0
    for j in range(2, N-1,2):
        s_even += integral_theta(r, rline, a+j*h, sigma)

    return h/3*(integral_theta(r, rline, a, sigma) + integral_theta(r, rline, b, sigma) + 4*s_odd + 2*s_even)

def i_r(r, sigma):
    M = 1000
    x, w = ss.roots_hermitenorm(M)
    s = 0
    for h in range(M):
        s += i_theta(r, x[h], sigma)*w[h]
    return s/2/np.pi/sigma**2
```

Comment: No need to do any tricky stuff: There is a corresponding Gaussian quadrature with this weight function on the interval $[0,\infty]$. Just search for "half-open Hermite quadrature".

Comment: Or search for "Gauss–Laguerre quadrature".

Comment: @cos_theta: but Gauss-Laguerre has a different weight function as the one in the OP, i.e. $e^{-r}$ instead of $e^{-r^2/2}$.